# IdTcpServer some times don't retrieve the informations at Disconnect event

Tags: delphi

I don't know why but sometimes when disconnect event on log he don't retrieve the ip and hostname, maybe because already disconnected before retrieve the informations? and if yes how solve it?

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  DadosConexao : TClient;
begin
  DadosConexao := TClient(AContext);

  DadosConexao.PeerIP      := AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
  DadosConexao.HostName    := GStack.HostByAddress(DadosConexao.PeerIP);
  DadosConexao.Connected   := Now;
  DadosConexao.LastAction  := DadosConexao.Connected;

  TThread.Queue(nil,
  procedure
  begin
    Memo2.Lines.Add(Format('[%s][%s] connect', [TimeToStr(Now), DadosConexao.PeerIP, DadosConexao.HostName]));
  end);

  RefreshListBox;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  DadosConexao : TClient;
begin
  DadosConexao := TClient(AContext);

  TThread.Queue(nil,
  procedure
  begin
    Memo2.Lines.Add(Format('[%s][%s] disconnect', [TimeToStr(Now), DadosConexao.PeerIP, DadosConexao.HostName]));
  end);

  RefreshListBox;
end;
```

example, here it get the informations:

[17:12:38][192.168.15.3] connect

[17:12:38][192.168.15.3] disconnect

and here no:

[17:12:38][192.168.15.3] connect

[17:12:38][] disconnect

Comment: Using TThread.Synchronize instead TThread.Queue appear solved. So he try use something who already are disconnected (sometimes) using Queue?

Comment: I don't recommend using `TThread.Synchronize()` in the `OnDisconnect` event. Doing so can cause a deadlock when the main UI thread tries to deactivate the server (the `Active` property waits on the client thread to terminate, but the thread waits on `Synchronize()` to exit, but `Synchronize()` waits for the `Active` property to exit). `TThread.Queue()` is safer since it doesn't block the calling thread..

Answer (score 1):

`TThread.Queue()` is asynchronous, it does not block the calling thread.  It queues the specified method/procedure and then exits immediately.  The main UI thread checks the queue for methods/procedures to run at its earliest convenience. So the `TIdContext` object is likely being destroyed before your the anonymous procedure actually runs in the main UI thread.

You need to change your logging code to have the anonymous procedure capture the individual string values rather than capturing the `TClient` object itself, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  DadosConexao : TClient;
  PeerIP, HostName: string;
begin
  DadosConexao := TClient(AContext);

  DadosConexao.PeerIP := AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
  DadosConexao.HostName := GStack.HostByAddress(DadosConexao.PeerIP);
  DadosConexao.Connected := Now;
  DadosConexao.LastAction := DadosConexao.Connected;

  PeerIP := DadosConexao.PeerIP;
  HostName := DadosConexao.HostName;

  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Memo2.Lines.Add(Format('[%s][%s][%s] connect', [TimeToStr(Now), PeerIP, HostName]));
    end
  );

  RefreshListBox;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  DadosConexao : TClient;
  PeerIP, HostName: string;
begin
  DadosConexao := TClient(AContext);

  PeerIP := DadosConexao.PeerIP;
  HostName := DadosConexao.HostName;

  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Memo2.Lines.Add(Format('[%s][%s][%s] disconnect', [TimeToStr(Now), PeerIP, HostName]));
    end
  );

  RefreshListBox;
end;
```

Which can then be taken a step further by wrapping the logging code into its own procedure:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.ClientStateUpdated(Client: TClient; Connected: Boolean);
var
  PeerIP, HostName: string;
begin
  PeerIP := Client.PeerIP;
  HostName := Client.HostName;

  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Memo2.Lines.Add(Format('[%s][%s][%s] %s', [TimeToStr(Now), PeerIP, HostName, iif(Connected, 'connect', 'disconnect')]));
    end
  );

  RefreshListBox;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  DadosConexao : TClient;
  PeerIP, HostName: string;
begin
  DadosConexao := TClient(AContext);

  DadosConexao.PeerIP := AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
  DadosConexao.HostName := GStack.HostByAddress(DadosConexao.PeerIP);
  DadosConexao.Connected := Now;
  DadosConexao.LastAction := DadosConexao.Connected;

  ClientStateUpdated(DadosConexao, true);
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  ClientStateUpdated(TClient(AContext), false);
end;
```

Comment: Great, solved the problem. A question about FDQuery and TIdTcpServer. i need do some operations (Select/Insert) on every new connection, and since every connection have your own thread you recommen? or maybe some kind of pool? i don't know.

Comment: You need a separate DB connection per thread. You can create a new connection per thread, or you can poll connections, it is your choice. I have gone both ways. In this case, I would use a pool. Have a thread grab a connection from the pool when needed, creating a new connection if none are available, do the DB work, and then put the connection back in the pool when done. And then check the pool periodically to close any connections that have not been used for awhile.

Comment: But don't generate problems like some databases have limit of concurrent connections?

Comment: Sometimes. All the more reason a connection pool is useful, you can set it up to not give out more connections than the server will allow.  If a thread can't get a connection, either wait until it can, or move on to other things.

Comment: Another question now about queue, queue i only use when i need send something outside connect/execute event of server right? inside i can use IOHandler.WriteLn normally right?

Comment: `TThread.Queue()` (and `TThread.Synchronize()`) are used when you need to execute code in the context of the main UI thread, such as UI control updates. If code doesn't need to run in the main UI thread, it should not be queued/synced at all. And yes, you can use the `IOHandler` of the provided `AContext` directly in the server's event handlers (however, I do not recommend *directly* accessing the `IOHandler` of OTHER CONTEXTS in a server event, though. There are better/safer ways to handle that when needed).

Comment: no no, what i mean is add a Queue as TIdThreadSafeStringList on TClient (TIdServerContext) and use it to add custom commands outside OnExecute event.

Comment: If you mean you want code outside of `OnExecute` to send data to clients, then yes, a queue that outside code can push data into and `OnExecute` can read from to write to its client is the preferred approach in most situations.

Comment: Yes, i did it. now i'm with a problem if i create a simple tcpclient and connect to my server it can be flooded, i can create many connections. How i can disconnect strange connections? i mean if at connect server don't receive the informations who need to procede.

Comment: Validate the connection in the `OnConnect` event as needed, and `Disconnect()` it if needed.

Comment: I'm trying, example i call ReadLn but it don't receive nothing if the client only connect but don't send anything. i'll post another question explaining that.

Comment: @PSDEVS you can set a timeout on that read and then disconnect the client if it elapses