# Disconnect unknow connections at TIdTcpServer OnConnect

Tags: delphi

I'm having a problem.  I created a `TIdTCPServer` but I need to prevent false/unknown connections.

I tried this:

```
procedure Wait(millisecs: Integer);
var
  tick: dword;
  AnEvent: THandle;
begin
  AnEvent := CreateEvent(nil, False, False, nil);
  try
    tick := GetTickCount + dword(millisecs);
    while (millisecs > 0) and (MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, AnEvent, False, millisecs, QS_ALLINPUT) <> WAIT_TIMEOUT) do begin
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      if Application.Terminated then Exit;
      millisecs := tick - GetTickcount;
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(AnEvent);
  end;
end;

procedure CheckCon(Con: Pointer);
begin
  Wait(5000);

  if TClient(Con).HWID = '' then TClient(Con).Connection.Disconnect;
  EndThread(0);
end;

constructor TClient.Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil);
var
  ThreadId : Cardinal;
begin
  inherited Create(AConnection, AYarn, AList);

  FCriticalSection  := TCriticalSection.Create;
  Queue             := TIdThreadSafeStringList.Create;

  BeginThread(nil, 0, @CheckCon, Self, 0, ThreadId);
end;
```

OnConnect event code:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Conexao : TClient;
  Retorno : TArray<String>;
  Query   : TFDQuery;
  Libera  : Boolean;
  IPEX    : Boolean;
begin
  Libera  := True;
  IPEX    := True;
  Conexao := TClient(AContext);
  Retorno := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn.Split(['#']);

  if Length(Retorno) = 0 then
  begin
    AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
    Exit;
  end;

  Conexao.IP          := AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
  Conexao.HWID        := Retorno[1];
  Conexao.Connected   := Now;
  Conexao.Ping        := Ticks;

  ClientStateUpdated(Conexao, RetornaTraducao(40));

TThread.Queue(nil,
              procedure
              begin
                Memo2.Lines.Add(Format(RetornaTraducao(36), [TimeToStr(Now), Conexao.IP, Conexao.HWID]));
              end);
end;
```

If I test creating a low number of unknown clients, it works good, but if I flood it with MANY connections, the application crashes. I need something like this to prevent unknown connections in my `TIdTCPServer`.

I tried calling

```
Memo2.Lines.Add(Format('[%s]', [AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn]));
```

in `IdTCPServer1Connect` to determine if the connection was my application, but if the client only connects and doesn't send anything, the line doesn't execute.

Comment: Added OnConnect code.

Comment: AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadTimeout should be the first line at OnConnect right? appear it solved, sill be able to flood, but if don't receive nothing server disconnect the connection. How much ms it should be good?

Comment: That is up to you to decide based on your actual needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a worker thread inside of `TClient`'s constructor is completely unnecessary (the `TClient` object is already run in a thread created by the server). You can simply set a 5 second timeout on the `ReadLn()` call itself and be done with it.

Also, `TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component, its events are fired in the context of worker threads, so access to UI controls like `Memo2` MUST by synchronized with the UI thread or else bad things happen.

Try something more like this:

```pascal
constructor TClient.Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil);
begin
  inherited Create(AConnection, AYarn, AList);

  FCriticalSection  := TCriticalSection.Create;
  Queue             := TIdThreadSafeStringList.Create;
end;

...

// code adapted from my reply to your previous question:
//
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/58479489/65863
//
// tweak as needed...
//
procedure TForm1.ClientStateUpdated(Client: TClient; const Msg: string);
var
  IP, HWID: string;
begin
  IP := Client.IP;
  HWID := Client.HWID;

  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Memo2.Lines.Add(Format(RetornaTraducao(36), [TimeToStr(Now), IP, HWID, Msg]));
    end
  );
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Conexao : TClient;
  Retorno : TArray<String>;
begin
  Conexao := TClient(AContext);
  Retorno := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(LF, 5000).Split(['#']);

  if (Length(Retorno) < 2) or (Retorno[1] = '') then
  begin
    AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
    Exit;
  end;

  Conexao.IP          := AContext.Binding.PeerIP;
  Conexao.HWID        := Retorno[1];
  Conexao.Connected   := Now;
  Conexao.Ping        := Ticks;

  ClientStateUpdated(Conexao, RetornaTraducao(40){'connect'});
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Conexao : TClient;
begin
  Conexao := TClient(AContext);

  if Conexao.Connected <> 0 then
    ClientStateUpdated(Conexao, RetornaTraducao(...){'disconnect'});
end;
```

Comment: A question this delay ar ReadLn don't block (wait) the connection for 5 seconds? receiving information or not? like freeze every new connections for 5 seconds before continue?

Comment: Using this code i don't know why but after some connections/disconnections server stop receive connection